# Serge Lang: Multivariable Derivative Definition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition

I'm confused about how the absolute value appears in the following formula (**) in Serge Lang's "Multivariable Calculus of Several Variables".

Context:  He has already defined the single-variable derivative as the limit of the difference quotient.  He proceeds to define the following function for a fixed x:

$g(h) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} -f'(x)$

This is then rewritten as:

$f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + hg(h)$

After a comment on how this is defined for all values of $h$, since the definition works for $h\not = 0$ and we specifically define $g(0) = 0$, we get this paragraph:

"Furthermore, we can replace $h$ by $-h$ if we replace $g$ by $-g$.  Thus we have shown that if $f$ is differentiable, there exists a function $g$ such that:

(**) $f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + |h|g(h)$

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} g(h) = 0$

Question:  Where does the absolute value come from?  Also, is what the point of replacing $h$ and $g$ with their negatives.

I've tried calculating $-g(h)$ from the original formula, and I get:

$-g(h) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{-h} +f'(x)$

which leads back to the original rewrite:

$f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + hg(h)$

So I get that a change to $-g$ corresponds with a change to $-h$.

But the right-hand side of (**) is:  $f'(x)h + |h|g(h)$

Why is there absolute value in the second term, but not the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of $g$, relationship

$$ f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + {hg(h)}$$

holds for any $h$.

Replacing $h$ by $-h$, we also have:

$$ f(x-h)-f(x) = f'(x)(-h) + (-h)g(-h),$$

which is equivalent to

$$ f(x-h)-f(x) = f'(x)(-h) + h(-g)(-h).$$

The function that exists and respects Lang's relationship is $\alpha$ defined as

$\alpha(h)=g(h)$ if $h$ is positive, $\alpha(h)=(-g)(h)$ if $h$ is negative, and $\alpha(0)=0$. Its limit at $0$ is $0$ because both $g$ and $-g$ have limits $0$ at $0$.

It is this new function (not original $g$) that gives:

$$ f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + |h|\alpha(h)$$

for any $h$.

Note that for any non-zero $h$, we simply have:

$$ \alpha(h)=\frac{hg(h)}{|h|}.$$

Comment: Ah, I see...the new function is "not original g".  So it's essentially a poor notation issue in the book.  Thanks!

Comment: I thought that what caused the absolute value is that we can give two definitions of $g$, the first one $$g(h)=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)$$ so from the first one we get $$f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h + {hg(h)}$$ and from the second $$f(x+h)-f(x) = f'(x)h -{hg(h)}$$ so is that why we should put the absolute value?? @ir7